# Red and green lines

Tags: error, axis

I opened a file that I was working on and there are tones of red lines and green ones I opened up a few different files and that didn't have it does anyone know a fix?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your file to see if it is something related to that file? Maybe it is your GPU fault, there are more possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this:
[image]

You probably didn't saw that city because it has big dimensions and you wrote in 999999999999 or something like that, maybe 100000000000..., this can cause this issue, change it to something like 10000 and your issue is gone:
[image]

By the way, those lines are your Axis X and Y, if you enable Z, you can also see Z with them, it is just graphic glitch because of that way too high number

Comment: Thanks i will see tomorrow if it fixes it.