# How to fix bad graphic on shading view?

Tags: shaders

The graphic suddenly looks weird. How to fix this?
The problem only happens on shading view.

[image]

Comment: I am not exactly sure what I am looking at but try to change value Clip Start at the top right in View to something like 0.1 and let me know if it helped

Comment: Yea, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Just to add more, this is same thing: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/242914/128477 ----- If you change Clip End to way too big value it will start to glitch your xyz axis, if you set your clip start way too low combined with end being high it will create this similar graphic glitch that you experienced, value like 0.0001 is only good if you are working with something really small